# How to reuse a TypeScript union type from a 3rd party @types module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types, union-types

So I'm new to TypeScript and wanted to know if there's a way to reuse a union type from a 3rd party @types module.

Example, in `@types/node` we have the following union type for buffer encodings:

```js
// Buffer class
type BufferEncoding = "ascii" | "utf8" | "utf-8" | "utf16le" | "ucs2" | "ucs-2" | "base64" | "latin1" | "binary" | "hex";
```

And if I have a utility function that passes a value through to `Buffer.from()` I am required to specify a union type that is compatible with the "BufferEncoding" type, I can't just use "string" like so:

```js
export function convertToBuffer(input: string | Buffer, encoding?: string): Buffer {
    if (input instanceof Buffer) return input;
    return Buffer.from(input, encoding);
}
```

Obviously I could just copy and paste the BufferEncoding type from `@types/node` but this doesn't keep my code DRY, and I am not allowed to import from `@types/*` modules.

```js
export type BufferEncoding = "ascii" | "utf8" | "utf-8" | "utf16le" | "ucs2" | "ucs-2" | "base64" | "latin1" | "binary" | "hex";

export function convertToBuffer(input: string | Buffer, encoding?: BufferEncoding): Buffer {
    if (input instanceof Buffer) return input;
    return Buffer.from(input, encoding);
}
```

I'm not interested in using the "any" type or other methods that loosen the strictness of the type checks. I suspect what I'm asking may not be possible and that's fine.

Comment: You shouldn't import from `@types/*`. Just use `BufferEncoding` without importing - it should available in node environment

Comment: ** once `@types/node` installed

Comment: So this worked with the Node types but I can't get it to work with other type packages, I get the error `Cannot find name 'X'.ts(2304)`. Is this likely something I'm doing wrong or could it be a problem with the type package I'm using?

Comment: types from other packages you should be import regularly `import { Foo } from 'bar'` where `bar` is name of the package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks very much to Aleksey for pointing me in the right direction. It turns out I had a couple of different issues here that were compounding.

1. **Types for Node core packages** - it is indeed as simple as running `npm install --save @types/node` and then the types such as `BufferEncoding` are available to use without importing anything.

```js
export function doSomething(encoding?: BufferEncoding): void { ... }
```

2. **Destructuring nested objects** - the TypeScript compiler isn't able to infer the types of variables if you re-assign them using destructuring or otherwise.

It's a common pattern to destructure objects to pull out the variables we need:

```js
import errors from './errors';
const { http: { BadRequestError } } = errors;

export function doSomething(err: BadRequestError): void { ... }
```

However, this causes problems for the TypeScript compiler and gives errors such as:

- `'BadRequestError' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. ts(2749)`
- `Parameter 'err' of exported function has or is using private name 'BadRequestError'. ts(4078)`

The solution is to avoid reassignment and reference the variables directly:

```js
import errors from './errors';

export function doSomething(err: errors.http.BadRequestError): void { ... }
```